# Automatic Formatting of Input VBA/Word

Tags: excel, vba, automation, ms-word

How do you automatically Format an Input?

For Example I have two Inputs

```
    Input 1: John
    Input 2: Doe
```

And I want to have it automatically fill in this Data in a particular Format. In the end it should output/insert me this -> **JoDo**

I know how to insert the Full Input via VBA but is there a way to determine only like the first 2 Letters from Input 1 then the First two Letters from Input2 ? Not sure but I would expect it kinda like this? [Input1(1,2) + Input2(1,2)]

Comment: look for `Left` and `&` ...

Comment: Look at string functions in Word vba. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/string-functions and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/string-manipulation-summary and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.left?view=netframework-4.7.2.